# How to make NVARCHAR column in phpMyAdmin?

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin, sqldatatypes, nvarchar

I need to use NVARCHAR because I have to deal with cyrillic symbols, but phpMyadmin says that this data type is unrecognized. I use phpMyAdmin 4.6.4 and MySQL 5.7. How to solve this problem?

[image]

Comment: Issue added for phpMyAdmin: https://github.com/phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin/issues/13306

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`NVARCHAR` exists only for "compatibility" with other vendors.  Use `VARCHAR` and specify `CHARACTER SET utf8mb4`, to get the "N".

5.7 is happy with NVARCHAR; it seems that phpMyAdmin is not.